# naive-bayes-classifier (top ten words)

Tags: python

I want to List the 10 most distinguishable words for each category that separate the category from other categories with alpha = 0.01 Associate these words with the topics in the category. I write some code then I am stuck I do not How can I list 10 word.

```
   >>> import numpy as np
>>> import operator
>>> from sklearn import datasets, feature_extraction, naive_bayes, metrics, linear_model
>>> data_train = datasets.fetch_20newsgroups(subset = 'train', shuffle = True, random_state =
2016, remove = ('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))
>>> data_test = datasets.fetch_20newsgroups(subset = 'test', shuffle = True, random_state =
2016, remove = ('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))
>>> categories = data_train.target_names
>>> target_map = {}
>>> for i in range(len(categories)):
    if 'comp.' in categories[i]:
        target_map[i] = 0
    elif 'rec.' in categories[i]:
        target_map[i] = 1
    elif 'sci.' in categories[i]:
        target_map[i] = 2
    elif 'misc.forsale' in categories[i]:
        target_map[i] = 3
    elif 'talk.politics' in categories[i]:
        target_map[i] = 4
    else:
        target_map[i] = 5


>>> y_temp = data_train.target
>>> y_train = []
>>> for y in y_temp:
    y_train.append(target_map[y])


>>> y_temp = data_test.target
>>> y_test = []
>>> for y in y_temp:
    y_test.append(target_map[y])


>>> count_vectorizer = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(min_df = 0.01, max_df = 0.5, stop_words = 'english')
>>> x_train = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(data_train.data)
>>> 
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> x_test = count_vectorizer.transform(data_test.data)
>>> mnb = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(alpha = 0.01)
>>> mnb.fit(x_train, y_train)
MultinomialNB(alpha=0.01, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
>>> y_pred = mnb.predict(x_test)
>>> print('accuracy of Multinomial Naive Bayes: ', metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
accuracy of Multinomial Naive Bayes:  0.692910249602
>>> mnb = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(alpha = 0.001)
>>> mnb.fit(x_train, y_train)
MultinomialNB(alpha=0.001, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
>>>  y_pred = mnb.predict(x_test)

SyntaxError: unexpected indent
>>> y_pred = mnb.predict(x_test)
>>>  print('accuracy of Multinomial Naive Bayes: ', metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

SyntaxError: unexpected indent
>>> print('accuracy of Multinomial Naive Bayes: ', metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
accuracy of Multinomial Naive Bayes:  0.692379182156
>>> mnb = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(alpha = 0.1)
>>> mnb.fit(x_train, y_train)
MultinomialNB(alpha=0.1, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
>>> y_pred = mnb.predict(x_test)
>>> print('accuracy of Multinomial Naive Bayes: ', metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
accuracy of Multinomial Naive Bayes:  0.692379182156
>>> mnb = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(alpha = 1)
>>> mnb.fit(x_train, y_train)
MultinomialNB(alpha=1, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
>>> y_pred = mnb.predict(x_test)
>>> print('accuracy of Multinomial Naive Bayes: ', metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
accuracy of Multinomial Naive Bayes:  0.691848114711
>>> mnb = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(alpha = 10)
>>> mnb.fit(x_train, y_train)
MultinomialNB(alpha=10, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
>>> y_pred = mnb.predict(x_test)
>>> print('accuracy of Multinomial Naive Bayes: ', metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
accuracy of Multinomial Naive Bayes:  0.686537440255
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Sorry.

Comment: So sorry for that do you . could you pleas told if I want to see the 10 top word in the text file. what should I write.

Comment: If you want people to help you on this site, you'll have to figure out how to make the questions easy to read (or, at least, no harder than is necessary). Suppose someone were explaining to you the problem. What would be the shortest thing you'd need to see what's the problem? Don't just slap down all the code, I suggest.

Comment: I write the code because I want to show you what I have done and which text I have used.  any way thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
count_vectorizer = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(min_df = 0.01, max_df = 0.5, stop_words = 'english')
x_train = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(data_train.data)
x_test = count_vectorizer.transform(data_test.data)
acc=[]
i=0
rr=[0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10]
for alp in [0,1,2,3,4]:
    mnb = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(alpha = alp)
    mnb.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = mnb.predict(x_test)
    print('accuracy of Multinomial Naive Bayes for alpha ',rr[alp],'=', metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
    acc.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))


import operator
pos,m = max(enumerate(acc), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print("Max accuracy=",m," for alpha=",rr[pos])

for ss in [0,1,2,3,4,5]:
    mnb = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(alpha = rr[pos])
    mnb.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = mnb.predict(x_test)

    acc[alp]=metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    feature_names = count_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    diff = mnb.feature_log_prob_[ss,:] - np.max(mnb.feature_log_prob_[-ss:])

    name_diff = {}
    for i in range(len(feature_names)):
       name_diff[feature_names[i]] = diff[i]

       names_diff_sorted = sorted(name_diff.items(), key = op.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
    for i in range(10):
       print(ss,names_diff_sorted[i])
```